# How to make Database Caching?

Tags: database, caching, client-server, hazelcast

**How can I configure Hazelcast to do caching for my database?**

Apparently my question has less chances to get answers because it is a technology related.

So in general words **How to redirect the client's queries to the cache? And if the latter doesn't have the data, how to indicate to it (to the cache) that it should retrieve it from the database?**

INFO : I have an Oracle database and Hazelcast Client/Server architecture.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to to talk to the Hazelcast IMap; which extends the ConcurrentMap/Map from java.

So e.g.

```
IMap<String, Employees> employees = hazelcastInstance.getMap("employees");
```

And you need to get your data like Employee e = employees.get("123");

The second step is the configure the employees IMap with a MapLoader.

```
<map name="employeeMap">
    <map-store enabled="true">
        <class-name>foo.bar.EmployeeMapLoader</class-name>
    </map-store>
</map>
```

You do this in your Hazelcast properties file, if put in the right location, will automatically will be picked up.

The MapLoader is an interface provided by Hazelcast you need to implement:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/core/MapLoader.java

Here you do your database statements.

For an example check:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-book-examples/tree/master/chapter-distributed-map/mapstore

This is an example with the MapStore so you can also write changes back to the database. But if you don't need that, just use a MapLoader (MapStore extends MapLoader).